# How to get the name of a variable instead of its value in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, debugging

I write a lot of debugging code in plpgsql along the lines:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'var1 = %', var1;
```

(there can be more than one variable to print out).

Is it possible to avoid having to repeat the variable `var1` every time by writing a PostgreSQL function (say `myprint`) so that

```
SELECT myprint(var1);
```

will generate the same output as `RAISE NOTICE 'var1 = %', var1;`?

The problem is that I know how to get the value of `var1` in the function but I don't know how to get the name `var1`. Is there some call-stack or context magic in plpgsql that can provide the name of the variable passed to `myprint`?

(This is with PostgreSQL 12.1 or later)